# How could my dataset possibly affect the alternate row coloring in my tablix?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

(This is for SSRS 2012)

As stated above, I have a very simple report with a dataset and a tablix.  I came to the realization that I want another tablix on this report, and therefore I have to expand my dataset, which is no big deal.  Same dataset, just more stuff in it.  However, after I get the dataset squared away, my row highlighting refuses to function correctly; instead of highlighting every even row, it now highlights every row.  Reverting back to the older version of the dataset fixes this problem.

This is the (very common) code I'm using for the row highlighting:

```
=IIF(RowNumber(Nothing) MOD 2, "transparent", "WhiteSmoke")
```

My question is mainly philosophical at this point: How on God's green Earth could more lines of SQL in the query possibly affect the row highlighting?  What should I even be looking at in the new version of my dataset to approach this problem?

Forgive my brevity and ignorance, this is at the end of a frustrating work day, and I'm pretty new to SSRS.  Right now I'm comparing both versions of the dataset AND scouring the .xml of the tablix to see if I can find any clues, but to no avail.  I can provide an .rdl file if needed, but I'd have to do a lot of scrubbing first and was hoping there might be some overarching philosophies that I'm just not aware of.

Thanks in advance!  And sorry if this has been answered before, I couldn't find anything in my first search...

Comment: can you show a small sample of data from each version of the dataset

Comment: Is this row highlighting code a tablix property? Or a dataset property? Or a property on the tablix row?

Comment: Alan - let me do some scrubbing and I'll get back to you, I'm a little busy at work already so it might take some time.

Comment: Cucumber - it's a property on the tablix row.  That code is in the BackgroundColor property of the row.

Comment: I had a bunch of other questions, but I think it all comes down Alan's question. We may be able to help if we get a glimpse of the datasets in question.

Comment: It so happens, sometimes, that code/query/and other changes are not reflected properly into the report, as has happened with me a no. of times. So, I would suggest you save your report, close the SSRS, restart it and resume your work again, and see if it fixes the problem, (provided there wasn't any other query related issue, in God's green Earth !)